# How to call 'open3d.cuda.pybind.visualization.Visualizer' in Windows10?

Tags: python, open3d

I have installed open3d 0.15.1 on both windows10 and ubuntu 18.04. And pytorch and cuda have been both installed. When I call the following codes:

```py
vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
...
vis.add_geometry(points)
```

I found in Ubuntu, the `o3d.visualization.Visualizer()` is an `open3d.cuda.pybind.visualization.Visualizer`, while in windows 10,  the `o3d.visualization.Visualizer()` is an `open3d.cpu.pybind.visualization.Visualizer`.
How could I use the `open3d.cuda.pybind.visualization.Visualizer` in windows 10?